# Distribution of sum of two independent Poisson random variables $\mathcal{P_1}$, $\mathcal{P_2}$ with dependent rates

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, reference-request, poisson-distribution

Let say I have $\mathcal{P_1} \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda_1) $ and $\mathcal{P_2} \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda_2)$, where $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are two dependent random variables. I know that if  $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are indendent random variables then we know that the distribution of $\mathcal{P_1}+\mathcal{P_2}$ is $\text{Poisson}(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)$. However, it is not clear to me what happen if $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are dependent rdvs. Is there any result for this kind of problems? Many thanks!

Comment: No. If they are nor independent and you don't have any further informatoin on how they are related to each other you cannot say anything about the sum.

Comment: I know that if the Poisson r.v. are independent, then there sum is a Poisson r.v., but I’m not familiar with a Poisson r.v. with the parameter $\lambda$ that is also a random variable. Are $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, generated by some process, after which the Poisson r.v. are generated, so that the lambdas are constant at that point?

Comment: $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are *parameters*, not random variables themselves. If you are considering the case where e.g. $\lambda_2$ is a function of $\lambda_1$, perhaps $\lambda_2 = \lambda_1^2$, then perhaps we could say something. Is that what you meant?

Comment: You can also do mixtures or conditioning: let $X$ be Poisson distributed with mean $\lambda$ conditional on $\Lambda =\lambda$ where $\Lambda$ is some other RV that is positive and real (say, uniform on an interval). Then you could try to extend this to sums and study the unconditional distribution, but no guarantee it’ll be simple.

Comment: $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ depend on previous Poisson processes. It is a sequence of Poisson rdvs generated in a sequence of time steps.